# Is it possible to data-bind more than one type at a time?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I want to change the background image of my app via the click of a button. The problem is I am already binding a click to it. Is there any way that I can change it by the button?

```
<button type="button" name="grid30" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs active" data-bind="click: function() {app.changeVisibleDays(29);};">30-days</button>
```

Comment: sorry do ignore the div at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using an in-line function as your click handler, you can just add a function call to change the background image in there as well:

```
<button type="button" name="grid30" class="btn btn-primary btn-xs active" 
        data-bind="
            click: function() {
              app.changeVisibleDays(29);
              app.changeBackground();
            };">30-days</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

I suppose KnockoutJS encourages to use MVVM appproach to solve such tasks:

```js
var viewModel = function() {
 return {
   image: ko.observable(""),
    changeBackground: function() {
     this.image("url(http://www.w3schools.com/html/pic_mountain.jpg)");
    }
  }
};

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

```css
.button {
  background-color: gray;
  cursor: pointer;
  psdding: 5px;
}
.button:hover {
  background-color: lightgray;
}


.image {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.2.0/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div class='button' data-bind='click: changeBackground'>Change background</div>
</br>
<div class='image' data-bind='style: { backgroundImage: image}'></div>
```

#### Update 1

The "changeBackground" handler is a place to write your business logic, e.g.

```
app.changeVisibleDays(29);
```

chnange background or do something else.

If you already have a model ("app") you can embed this handler into "app" object:

data-bind="click: app.changeBackground"

The "changeBackground" is a sample name for button click handler. Of course in the RWA you will change its name on something more appropriate.

Comment: this approach only replaces the existing handler OP was using, or just adds a new button. OP wanted the button to call `changeVisibleDays` as well as update the background

Comment: He can execute any additional code in the "changeBackground" handler of the view model. Of course he can rename the handler.

Comment: @dperry KnockoutJS promotes the MVVM approach, that separates code from markup. I think it is better to put logic into model, at least into view model :)

Comment: I agree completely. as much as I dislike pushing a quick fix as an answer, I'd hate even more to have OP give up with a "rewrite" type answer. You still get an upvote from me